# createObjectURL giving not enough arguments

Tags: clojurescript, javascript-interop

I want to get the url of a `blob`, and I'm doing the following:

```
(.. js/window -URL createObjectURL blob)
```

to mimic the JS

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments (at createObjectURL)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your use is incorrect. Needs an extra pair of parens so `blob` becomes an actual argument and not the "next" step.

```
(.. js/window -URL (createObjectURL blob))
```